# How to recover data from a deleted pen-drive?

Tags: 14.04, data-recovery

[image: disk utility]

I accidentally deleted my pen drive partition.

How can I recover the data from the usb-pen-drive?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to recover the data from the drive then

1. sudo apt-get install gparted
2. sudo apt-get install gpart
3. sudo gparted
4. In the upper right hand corner of gparted choose your pen drive device
5. Under **Device** choose **Attempt Rescue**

The software will scan for the super blocks of the OS and rebuild your partition sector using that data. Just follow the instructions. Once rebuilt and written you will then have access to the pen drive after reinserting into your system.

Good luck